# Android Google SignIn error 12500 while signing in with school account in a family link managed device

Tags: java, android, authentication, google-oauth, google-signin

I am writing to you because I could not find any answer to my problem. I'm creating an android (java) application for a school that involves logging in with google to get only email, name, surname and id. I used the example google-service-master -SignInActivity- to create the login and everything works. The problem is for those devices that are managed by the parent through the family link. On these devices it is possible to add a school account but it gives the error signInResult:failed code=12500 when trying to log in. I set the user type as internal in the OAuth consent screen because I want to make the application usable only by users of my organization, but even setting it as test the error still appears. I also tried to use the google-service-master example directly and it works by logging in with the child's managed account, but not with the added school account which always returns the same 12500 error. Could anyone tell me how I can proceed? Thank you